# WP_Query: How to test for sticky posts before assigning posts_per_page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any way to 'test' whether there are Sticky Posts?
If there IS a sticky post, I'd like to use `'posts_per_page' => '3'` and if not, use `4`, as I'm finding that Sticky Posts add to the 'posts per page' which breaks the layout :(

I have a WP_query as follows:

```
$article_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => '3',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            );
            $article_query = new WP_Query($article_args);
```

Is that possible, maybe to test for this before the `args` array and use the appropriate number?

Yes, I have considered `ignore_sticky_posts` but I do want to include them still.

Any advice from someone who knows PHP better than me?! :/

Thanks. Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sticky post is saved as an option which you can check with `$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );`. This returns an array with post ID's. You can simply just check if the option is empty or not, and then modify your arguments accordingly

You can do something like this

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
if( $sticky ) {
    $article_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
}else{
    $article_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '4',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
}

$article_query = new WP_Query($article_args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, but there probably is another way to achieve what you're after.

You could simply grab the latest sticky post, and show that first, and then, in a second query, grab the rest of the posts (or the next 3, anyway).

That way, you'll get 1 sticky (if it exists) and 3 normal, per page.

We don't know your end goal here, so this could be unusable for you.

Comment: Thanks Mike. The goal is to have a maximum of 4 posts, whether this includes Stickies or not. The reason being that they are in a 2-across 2-down layout, so having 5 upsets the layout.

It seems this cannot be done in the way I was hoping though, so may need another approach, perhaps pulling in 3 posts and telling the client always mark one sticky.

Thanks again

Comment: You could always grab the stickies first, count them, and then decide how many normal ones you need

Comment: There is actually a simple solution :-). Check my answer